# How to split a polygon in a set of simple polygons

Tags: c#, sql-server, geospatial

I retrieve a complexe polygon from an SQL spatial database, a DbGeometry in C#. Complex means that this polygon is defined as an exterior ring and one or more interior rings (like a donut).

Is there a simple way to transform this complex polygon in a set of simple polygons. A simple polygon is a plygon without interior rings.

Thanks,
Mickaël

Comment: Are you looking for just the outer boundary or an area that represents the polygon defined by the outer boundary (sans holes)?

Comment: No, I search a set of polygons which cover the same area as the polygon with holes. For a donut I want to retrieve a "C" and a inverted "C".

Comment: I don't understand the "C" and inverted "C" comment. Maybe some explicit (but simple) days would help.

Comment: @mvera do you only have POLYGON instances or are some MULTIPOLYGONs? I understand that if you have a POLYGON (a donut with a hole for instance) you want to return only the outer boundary.  But what do you want if you have a MULTIPOLYGON (for instance a single object with two donuts in it)? Do you want a MULTIPOLYGON  back which has both outer boundaries of the two donuts?

Comment: I want a multipolygon built with polygons without holes.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with DbGeometries for a while and [this article](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2009/12/26/Displaying-spatial-data-in-WPF-from-SqlGeometry-to-PathGeometry.aspx) provides a great tool to manipulate it.

I suspect this cannot be as simple as `return myGeo.ExteriorRing;` so, as required in comments, here come some code I came to (based on the article) :

```
//handling of LineStrings (I use this to build WPF Path for example)
        private static object LineStringToSomething(DbGeometry sqlGeometry)
        {
            object result = null;
            DbGeometry curPoint;
            System.Windows.Point startPoint = new System.Windows.Point()
            {
                X = sqlGeometry.PointAt(1).XCoordinate.Value,
                Y = sqlGeometry.PointAt(1).YCoordinate.Value
            };

            curPoint = sqlGeometry.PointAt(1);

            for (int i = 2; i <= sqlGeometry.PointCount; i++)
            {
                //Do something with the line between curPoint and PointAt(i)

                curPoint = sqlGeometry.PointAt(i);
            }

            return result;
        }

        //Defines an extension method on DbGeometry objects
        //usage :
        // myOwnGeometry = myGeo.AsSimpleGeometry();
        public static object AsSimpleGeometry(this DbGeometry sqlGeometry)
        {
            object result = null;

            switch (sqlGeometry.SpatialTypeName.ToLower())
            {
                case "point":
                    //Here we found a point

                    return result;

                case "polygon":
                    // A Spacial Polygon is a collection of Rings
                    // A Ring is a Closed LineString, i.e. a collection of lines.
                    List<object> lotOfGeos = new List<object>();
                    // Outer Ring
                    return LineStringToSomething(sqlGeometry.ExteriorRing);

                    // Inner Rings (holes in the donut)
                    for (int i = 1; i <= sqlGeometry.InteriorRingCount; i++)
                    {
                        //just comment to ignore the inner loops
                        lotOfGeos.Add(LineStringToSomething(sqlGeometry.InteriorRingAt(i)));
                    }

                    return lotOfGeos;

                case "linestring":
                    // Return a PathFigure
                    return LineStringToSomething(sqlGeometry);

                case "multipoint":
                case "multilinestring":
                case "multipolygon":
                case "geometrycollection":
                    //Here we handle a collection of points, polygons and/or lines
                    List<object> moreGeos = new List<object>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= sqlGeometry.ElementCount.Value; i++)
                    {
                        //Simply calling the same method on each item
                        moreGeos.Add(sqlGeometry.ElementAt(i).AsSimpleGeometry());
                    }

                    return moreGeos;

                default:
                    // Unrecognized Type
                    // Shall not happen
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

As I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve with your geometries, I can't be more specific with the handling of the geodata (especially in the `LineStringToSomething`)

Comment: This would be better as a comment as it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Sorry then... but I didn't felt like re-posting someone else code. There's just a bunch of lines to comment/cut to get the "simple" polygon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't see where the complex polygon is tranformed in a set of simple polygons in the article. I don't feel Geometry class will give me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to simplify a POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON geometry instance to essentially remove all holes.  What isn't clear is what you expect back when the instance is a MULTIPOLYGON, but I'm going to assume that you want all exterior boundaries within the same instance.

I therefore suggest the following:

First, define a method to simplify the geometry:

```
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    private static DbGeometry GetSimpleDbGeography(DbGeometry input)
    {
        // We can create geometry using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometryBuilder
        // We have to use this to reconstruct the geometry we want from the input as DbGeometry.ExteriorRing() returns a LINESTRING which is no good to us
        SqlGeometryBuilder builder = new SqlGeometryBuilder();

        // We MUST set an SRID
        builder.SetSrid(0);

        OpenGisGeometryType ourType;

        // We must set the type
        if (input.SpatialTypeName.ToUpper() == "POLYGON")
            ourType = OpenGisGeometryType.Polygon;
        else if (input.SpatialTypeName.ToUpper() == "MULTIPOLYGON")
            ourType = OpenGisGeometryType.MultiPolygon;
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Non Polygon received.");

        // Tell the Builder what we're creating
        builder.BeginGeometry(ourType);

        // This assumes we have a valid DbGeometry instance, otherwise .Value will cause an error
        int numberOfElements = input.ElementCount.Value;

        // Loop through each element, this will either be one (POLYGON) or more (MULTIPOLYGON)
        for (int i = 1; i < (numberOfElements + 1); i++)
        {
            // BeginGeometry only required for MULTIPOLYGON
            if (ourType == OpenGisGeometryType.MultiPolygon)
            {
                // Begin a POLYGON geometry
                builder.BeginGeometry(OpenGisGeometryType.Polygon);
            }

            // ElementAt() is not zero-based index
            DbGeometry element = input.ElementAt(i).ExteriorRing;

            // Start the figure with the first point
            builder.BeginFigure(element.StartPoint.XCoordinate.Value, element.StartPoint.YCoordinate.Value);

            // Lopp through remaining points
            for (int j = 2; j < (element.PointCount.Value + 1); j++)
            {
                // PointAt() is not zero-based index
                builder.AddLine(element.PointAt(j).XCoordinate.Value, element.PointAt(j).YCoordinate.Value);
            }

            // End the current polygon
            builder.EndFigure();

            // EndGeometry only required for MULTIPOLYGON
            if (ourType == OpenGisGeometryType.MultiPolygon)
            {
                // End the current Geometry
                builder.EndGeometry();
            }
        }

        // Finalise the geometry
        builder.EndGeometry();

        // Convert the construsted geometry back to a DbGeometry instance
        DbGeometry finalGeometry = DbGeometry.FromBinary(builder.ConstructedGeometry.STAsBinary().Buffer);

        return finalGeometry;
    }
```

Now simply call like this:

```
// Two sample donuts
DbGeometry donut1 = DbGeometry.FromText("POLYGON((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0),(1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1))", 0);
DbGeometry donut2 = DbGeometry.FromText("POLYGON((10 10, 13 10, 13 13, 10 13, 10 10),(11 11, 12 11, 12 12, 11 12, 11 11))", 0);

// A merged, double-donut
DbGeometry doubleDonut = donut1.Union(donut2);

// Produces POLYGON((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0))
DbGeometry donut1_simple = GetSimpleDbGeography(donut1);

// Produces MULTIPOLYGON(((10 10, 13 10, 13 13, 10 13, 10 10)),((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0)))
DbGeometry doubleDonut_simple = GetSimpleDbGeography(doubleDonut);
```

Essentially, it recreates the geometry as is but without any holes.  I actually enjoyed the challenge of putting this together!! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help but that's not what I was looking for. For donut1_simple I expected : MULTIPOLYGON(((1.5 0, 1.5 1, 1 1, 1 2, 1.5 2,   1.5 3, 0 3, 0 0, 1.5 0)),((1.5 0, 3 0, 3 3, 1.5 3, 1.5 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1.5 1, 1.5 0))). This geometry is made of polygons without holes but has the same shape, the same area than donut1.

Comment: @mvera So what you are saying is that you want to retain the hole, but not as a hole.  Or put another way, you want to cut the geometry in as many ways as needed to be able to cut around the hole(s) but so the look of the polygon is exactly the same as if it still had the hole?  If so,  What ever for? What are you trying to accomplish?  That certainly isn't simplifying it.